# How can I get the full query string of a page

Tags: php, javascript, url, joomla

I'm using joomla and acesef as a plugin and I need to get the full querystring as is. The problem is when I use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` it contains the joomla QS isntead of my custom parameters.

A javascript or PHP solution would do. thanks

Edit:
Sample URL www.test.com/sc/my-account.html?action=payment-method 
I want to get

```
action=payment-method
```

Instead I get

```
option=com_content&Itemid=4&id=16&lang=sc&view=article
```

Comment: could you give an example of the url?

Comment: `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is the best you're going to get. What kind of custom parameters are you talking about? Can you show an example?

Comment: www.test.com/sc/my-account.html?action=payment-method but the server variable contains the joomla query string (com_content...)

Comment: www.test.com/sc/my-account.html - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the one that solves my problem
var qs = window.location.search.substring(1);

Thanks everyone SO rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Joomla setup probably has a mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess that is ignoring the original GET parameters and rewriting the whole GET query string, you'll have to hack your way into the .htaccess file.

Or stop using Joomla.

Comment: @wnoveno: I'm not that into Javascript, but this question has a couple of solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery, check it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't get what's in the URL, you get what the server hands you. That includes parameters added by things such as `mod_rewrite`. If you need specific parameters then index `$_GET[]` appropriately, otherwise live with it.

Comment: I don't really need the specific parameters, I just need the whole thing so that I can pass it to another link on the page.